# How to create new function from the product of two interpolated functions?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

So I'm working on a programming project for my Extragalactic Astronomy class.  We are given two sets of files:  The first consists of sample spectra from a population of stars of different ages.  The second is a system response curve for Sloan Digital Sky Survey (SDSS) bands.

Essentially, the first gives us a series of flux measurements for different wavelengths.  The second tells us how much of this flux SDSS is going to see, and this response is also dependent on wavelength.  In the code below, I've taken in the data for one population of stars and one of the system response curves.  I then interpolate this data to obtain a continuous curve for both.

What I'm trying to do now is take these two interpolated functions and obtain their product.  I then need to integrate this product with respect to wavelength.  I've encountered a problem while trying to compute the product:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.integrate import quad

def main():

 pop = numpy.loadtxt("fnu_m62_0.001Gyr")              # Loads sample spectrum
 popint = interpolate.interp1d(pop[:,0], pop[:,1])    # Interpolates

 sysr = numpy.loadtxt("sdss_response/sys.u")          # Loads SDSS response for u band
 sysrint = interpolate.interp1d(sysr[:,0], sysr[:,1]) # Interpolates

 p = sysrint * popint                   # Takes product of two functions, assigns to p
 plt.plot(pop[:,0], p(pop[:,0]), 'b-')  # Plots p as function of wavelength for the sample population interval
```

Attempting to run this code gives me:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'interp1d' and 'interp1d'
```

So I guess there's an issue in using arithmetic on the interpolated functions.  But I can't really see why.  Is there a way to multiply these two functions to get a new, continuous function?

Answer (score 1):

`'interp1d'` is a function type, thus, we make a product function of it like so:

```
def p(x): return popint(x)*sysrint(x)
```